# Imported type cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

I seem to be having a very strange issue with Eclipse. Randomly my code will just break producing this error:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    ResultSet cannot be resolved to a type
    The method sqlResult(String, ArrayList<Object>) from the type SQLFactory refers to the missing type ResultSet
```

SQLFactory.java:

```
...
import com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet;

public class SQLFactory {

    private Connection conn;
    private static String dbName = "";
    private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eecoursework?characterEncoding=utf8" + dbName;
    private static String username = "root";
    private static String password = "...";

    public SQLFactory() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ResultSet sqlResult(String SQL, ArrayList<Object> paramVals) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
    ...
```

paramVals is simply a list of strings/ints

Changing the import from .ResultSet to .*, saving and reverting sometimes fixes it but not always or permanently. Closing eclipse, cleaning the project, cleaning Tomcat also sometimes fixes it but same issues as previous.

Really pulling my hair out on this one, I am having so many issues with Eclipse and Tomcat not co-operating, its very frustrating spending more time getting the IDE to work than producing code

Comment: Observation: The code is using `com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet`. There should be no need to use a vendor-specific resultset implementation. Instead, use the core Java [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html) interface. See also the [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) for examples. (But I don't know why this would cause randomly occurring problems.)

Comment: @andrewJames I've replaced it with that but no cigar, error still randomly occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning the project in Eclipse when the error occurs fixed this